# Datapoints ordering: catplot seaborn

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, jupyter-lab

- In the *df* all the color types are together after sorting, however, in the first plot Y1 is between Xs (see below).
- By adding the *col=* to build a grid, the order is even further broken up.
- How can you keep the color *types* together on the plot?
- I've tried *hue_order*, *order*, *col_order* without any success.
- Plot 1: need the orange X color types to be in order X3 > X2 > X1, not X3 > X2 > Y1 > X1
- Plot 2: need all the color types to be in order (one after another)

Thank you in advance!

**color_data.csv** = [image]

**color_data.csv**:

| YEAR | SITE | G_annoation | color | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | Alpha | Y1 | Y | A |
| 2017 | Alpha | X1 | X | A |
| 2016 | Alpha | X2 | X | B |
| 2018 | Alpha | X3 | X | B |
| 2017 | Alpha | Z1 | Z | B |
| 2017 | Alpha | T1 | T | A |
| 2018 | Alpha | T2 | T | A |
| 2016 | Alpha | T3 | T | A |

```
  df = pd.read_csv('color_data.csv') 
  g= sns.catplot(data=df.sort_values(by='color'),
           x="Type", y="G_annotation", hue="color")
```

[image]

```
  df = pd.read_csv('color_data.csv') 
  g= sns.catplot(data=df.sort_values(by='color'),
           x="Type", y="G_annotation", hue="color", col="YEAR")
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try making the column explicitly categorical (which lets you set an ordering)? `df['color'] = pd.Categorical(df['color'], ['X1','X2','X','Y1','Y2'])`?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes, I have. Same outcome still.. `convert_dic = {'G_annotation':'category', 'color':'category','Type':'category'}`    and   `df = df.astype(convert_dic) ` 

I also tried sorting it in order and via mergesort algo. 
`g= sns.catplot(data=df.sort_values(by=['YEAR','color'],kind='mergesort'), x="Type", y="G_annotation", hue="color", col='YEAR')`